# How to add lib directory to sys.path when installed with custom prefix

Tags: python, distutils, setup.py

I come from a C background with Autotools (./configure, make, make install) but have recently started to use Python. With Autotools I can install a program more or less anywhere on the system by doing a `./configure --prefix=/foo/bar`. I've found that most Python programs uses a similar system based on distutils, usually in a file called setup.py. However, I have noticed that if I install the project in a non-standard directory, for example by doing a `python setup.py install --prefix /foo/bar`, then the script in `/foo/bar/bin` will not be able to pick up packages which are installed into `/foo/bar/lib/pythonx.y/site-packages`.

I assume that somehow I have to add that directory to `sys.path` when the script is executed. How do I do that in a stable cross-platform manner? Or should I do something else?

Answer (score 1):

If your custom installdir is "foo", your python-root is "bar" and your package-root is "lib"
you might add this to your script:

```
import sys
from os.path import join
foo = "foo"
bar = "bar"
lib = "lib"
newbase = join(foo, bar, lib)
sys.path.append(newbase)
```

in your example:

```
foo ='foo'
bar = 'bar'
lib = '/lib/pythonx.y/site-packages'
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think that will solve the problem. I don't know beforehand where the program will be installed. It could be anywhere in the file system. I would have to use the relative path and take into account that x.y is different depending on the installed version of Python.

Comment: If you are using distutils, and aren'T afraid of getting your hands dirty ou might try to cusomize the setup-script. The doc-section, which might be useful are: http://docs.python.org/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.sysconfig

Comment: Also be aware of that the new sheriff in town seems to be pip: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip

Answer (score 0):

Another common tool is to use virtualenv to create another python repository that is not the system-wide one and install your package inside it.

```
>> pip install virtualenv
>> virtualenv --distutils test_env
>> source ./test_env/bin/activate
>> cd <your package>
>> python setup.py install
```